# Calling Generic function + lambda

Tags: vb.net, generics, lambda

I have this function in vb.net that I converted from C# for a project I'm working on.

```
Private Function GetAllFactory(Of T)(ByVal ctor As Construct(Of T)) As List(Of T)

    'TODO: Data Access stuff 
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim entities = New List(Of T)()

    For Each dataRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim entity As T = ctor(dataRow)
        entities.Add(entity)
    Next
    Return entities

End Function
```

and the following delegate

```
Private Delegate Function Construct(Of T)(ByVal dataRow As DataRow) As T
```

I tried converting the code to call the function from C# to vb.net

```
Return GetAllFactory(Of MyType)(row >= New MyType(row))
```

the above line doesn't work. I'm sort of stuck. I haven't used lambda much in C# and even less in vb.net.

MyType constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal dataRow As DataRow)
  .
  .
  .
 End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to call the GetAllFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Function` keyword in VB to write a lambda expression:

```
Return GetAllFactory(Of MyType)(Function(row) New MyType(row))
```

Note that `>=` is a comparison operator while `=>` is the lamda operator in C#. VB might give you some unexpected error message for code using `=>` as it accepts that as an undocumented alias for the `>=` operator.

Comment: that's great! Thanks Guffa. The >= was automatically converetd when I typed in => (I guess because the vb.net doesn't have a => to overload, it's >= ?)

Comment: @user872995: Rather because it recognised `=>` as an alias for `>=`, so it changed it to the documented form of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net lambda expressions look like this:

```
Return GetAllFactory(Of MyType)(Function(row) New MyType(row))
```